# Unable to Install Ubuntu in new PC (Threadripper 7995WX and WRX90E Motherboard)

Tags: 22.04

Motherboard: Pro WS WRX90E-SAGE SE
CPU: Threadripper 7995WX

The shop guy just completed building my PC. He installed Windows. I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS using a USB. I am getting this error after clicking on "Try or install Ubuntu" in the very first menu.

I can load Ubuntu if I click on "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)". But not when I click on "Try or install Ubuntu". I get this error and then nothing happens

[Error WRX90E Threadripper Linux failure creating named object ae_already_exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxyeM.jpg)

Please help, this is really expensive setup, and I can't install Linux!! I am noob in these matters. I am ready to hire professional help, but from where?

Comment: Have you tried a newer release of Ubuntu?  (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was four releases ago; if this is a newer computer made with new hardware; a recent release will have more success than a 2022-April (22.04) release).  You also didn't specify what 22.04 you're using; what stack is it?  Server with GA, Desktop using??  (22.04?  22.04.1? 22.04.2? 22.04.3?  22.04.4?  as you don't specify; plus Server & Desktop use different installers, have different defaults so please be specific)

Comment: Sorry. I am using Ubuntu desktop 22.04.3 LTS. I will try newer version (23.10)

Comment: The first reply here says, it could be malware. Did the shop guy install some malware, trying to steal my data or something? https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/11gcnvd/acpi_bios_error_bug_failure_creating_named_object/

Comment: For context, this motherboard just started selling 21 days ago. The shop guy did update the BIOS to latest version. But there are some firmware updates available named "PD firmware update tool for Linux". Not sure, If it is important to install. I am noob, so don't wanna mess with bios @guiverc

Comment: If you wanted Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ; the newest stack is available if you use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS media which is at RC currently...  Ubuntu 23.10 (the 2023-October) release is newer; also there are 2x ISOs (using different installers) for the Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop system.

Comment: I am able to install the Ubuntu in Safe Graphics. Does it make a difference? Should I install it in Safe graphics? Ideally I would like to use 22.04.3 LTS desktop. Since my older PC is using that. And I can transfer my programs easily without thinking twice about any compatibility issues.

Comment: If using 22.04.3 or older media for sure  (*installing with safe graphics*)... Post install you can use `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to let the system auto-install drivers (kernel modules) as well as applying all security fixes and updates that you'd get if using 22.04.4 media....  FYI:  Your older machine will be using 22.04.4 & will have since last weekend at least if you've been applying security fixes.... Systems upgrade before the ISO is officially released....

Comment: Yeah, I am using 22.04.4 in my older PC. To confirm your suggestion. This is what I should do: 1.) Install ubuntu in safe graphics. 2.) Do ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 3.) Be happy, and use ubuntu like a normal noob guy.

Comment: Also should I be worried about malware in BIOS or something? Since the reddit comment mentions it, and other posts also hint it could be bcz of a hack. https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/11gcnvd/acpi_bios_error_bug_failure_creating_named_object/

Comment: The description of the alleged malware on that Reddit page is very improbable. It mentions a remote DHCP server that your system connects to before the system has even properly booted. It is not impossible, but a BIOS bug is a much more likely cause. Notice that the commenter has no Karma to speak of.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You guys saved me tons of time & headache.

Answer (score 1):

hey i just did this with a 7975wx. when you go to install ubuntu the first time hit e in the install to edit the boot options and ask gpt where to put -nomodeset or nvidia.drm=1.nomodeset or something. im guesssing you have a pretty new gpu, i did a 4090. you need ubuntu to not load graphics drivers at first, this is a normal thing. the gpu stuff with the new gpus on 22.04 is a pain. but i do not recommend the newer one. i tried it at first and just bailed. just bring your problem and my comments here to gpt/google and youll get it. its a pita.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when install a 7985WX on this board. There is a VGA switch on the board I flipped to disable onboard VGA and then I ended up using IPMI to do the install of ubuntu and load the graphics drivers.

I was also installing Ubuntu 22.04 because it is the latest LTS release and I don't want to worry about unstable stuff when working.

One last thing-- after I loaded Ubuntu I had to fiddle a bunch of with the SecureBoot settings to get things to work. I think I ended up leaving Windows compatible on and then had to set a password to load the graphics drivers when doing SecureBoot. You may be able to disable secureboot entirely to avoid this.